# Can't select dropdown in selenium python

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

I am new to selenium. I have managed to login in to our work practice management system. So the basic setup is fine.

I am then faced with this:

[image: Screen after login]

I need to drop down the Work dropdown and select a premade report (All Tasks For Export):

[image: Dropdown]

I have tried a lot of stuff...... CSS Selector, Class, ID

But I always get error: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://xxxxx.senta.co/a/i/a')

WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[name='email']"))).send_keys("xxx@xxx.com")
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='password']"))).send_keys("xxxxxx")
            
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button#submit').click()

dropdown = Select(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'major#navjobs'))
```

But maybe I am selecting the wrong element entirely. I will post the HTML below. Maybe I understand the Selenium but not the HTML!! Thanks in advance.

[image]

And then the HTML for the elements in the list look like this:

[image]

OK here is the HTML of the page. Not sure it's going to help much!

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" ng-app="senta" se-file-drop="onFileSelect($files)" ng-controller="BodyCtrl" ng-class="{ selectfile:selectfile }"> <head> <base href="/"> <meta charset="utf-8"> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" /> <meta name="robots" content="noindex"> <link id="favicon" rel='icon' type='image/ico' sizes='32x32' href='https://dsik6juztonps.cloudfront.net/client/public/images/favicon.ico'> <title ng-bind="$root.notiftitle + $root.title + $root.appTitle">Loading...</title> <link href="https://dsik6juztonps.cloudfront.net/client/public/dist/lib/20211115/lib.css" rel="stylesheet" /> <link href="https://dsik6juztonps.cloudfront.net/client/public/dist/_m258abe0ebbf4d5628de49b9a35dff42e/style.css" rel="stylesheet" /> <script src="https://dsik6juztonps.cloudfront.net/client/public/dist/lib/20211115/prelib.min.js"></script> <script src="https://dsik6juztonps.cloudfront.net/client/public/dist/lib/20211115/momentjs/en-gb.js"></script> </head> <body id="{{$root.bodyId}}" class="droptarget {{userClass}} {{skinClass}}" ng-class="{ 'on-scrolled':notAtTop, 'preheader-on':preheaderOn, 'preheader2-on':preheader2On, 'preheadertimer-on':preheaderTimerOn }"> <div ng-if="$root.user.loggedin" ng-include="'https://dsik6juztonps.cloudfront.net/client/public/dist/_m258abe0ebbf4d5628de49b9a35dff42e/html/en-gb/header.html'" ng-controller="NavBarCtrl"></div> <div class="dropindic"> <div class="lightbox"></div> <div class="centred"> <p class="text" style="">Drop your files here to upload into Senta</p><i class="fa fa-file"></i> <p class="selectbutton">Alternatively: <input type="file" id="selectfile"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pseudoselect" ng-click="selectFile()">Select file</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-normal" ng-click="cancelSelectFile()">Cancel</button> </p> </div> </div> <div ng-if="deepheader" class="deepheader"></div> <div class="container"> <div ui-view> <div class="positioner"> <div class="notifier"> <span class="spinning"><span class="spinner"><i class="fa fa-spin fa-refresh"></i></span></span> <span class="msg">Loading...</span> </div> </div> </div> <div id="react-root"></div> </div> <div ng-if="$root.expressionfooter" ng-include="'https://dsik6juztonps.cloudfront.net/client/public/dist/_m258abe0ebbf4d5628de49b9a35dff42e/html/en-gb/settings/expression/footer.html'" ng-controller="ExpressionTesterCtrl" ></div> <div ng-if="$root.previewfooter" ng-include="'https://dsik6juztonps.cloudfront.net/client/public/dist/_m258abe0ebbf4d5628de49b9a35dff42e/html/en-gb/modal/preview-footer.html'"></div> <script src="https://dsik6juztonps.cloudfront.net/client/public/dist/lib/20211115/postlib.min.js"></script> <script src="https://dsik6juztonps.cloudfront.net/client/public/dist/_m258abe0ebbf4d5628de49b9a35dff42e/app.min.en-gb.js"></script> <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/1.9.638/pdf.min.js"></script> </body><script src="https://dsik6juztonps.cloudfront.net/react/static/js/en-gb/main.eda07c95.js"></script></html>
```

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). You may like to consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Can someone tell me how to copy and paste text out of inspect in chrome?! 

Comment: You can look at the "page source" to see the full HTML and copy-paste, also, please include the code you are using to attempt this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but show page source does not contain the code that inspect shows. I assume it's all in a javascript file. And there are loads of them......

Comment: OK I have added in my code with the error message. I am trying to use the Selector Gadget Chrome Extension to get the CSS Selector

Comment: @rlpmeredith "how to copy..." just select an HTML element and copy it like you would any text. Alternatively, use selenium to get raw an element's HTML mid-execution.

Comment: `'major#navjobs'` is wrong value - it means tag `<major id="navjobs">` but HTML doesn't have tag `<major>`. It should be rather `.major` with `dot` to search `class="major"`

Comment: there is other problem - `Select()` works with standard tags `<select>` and `<option>` but this page doesn't use these tags - it creates menu using `<ul>`, `<li>` and you will have to use normal code to get element `Work`, click it, next get all elements in menu and click one object on list.

Comment: BTW: this element would need `'#navjobs .major'` instead of `'major#navjobs'`, and `.click()` it, and next get alll `#navjobs .work-dropdown li a` and click one of the element on list

Answer (score 0):

It's look like you want find element `By.CSS_SELECTOR` like you are using `By.XPATH`.

For example, if you want to find `<ul>` which contains here on your screenshot

[image]

you can use:

1. `driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'dropdown-menu')`
2. `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.dropdown-menu')`
3. `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//ul[@class='dropdown-menu']')`
4. `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//ul[@id='work-dropdown'][@class='dropdown-menu'])`

***but i can't understand what you are looking for...***

UPDATE:

try to find all `<li>` with `ng-repeat='viewt in viewst track by viewt._id'`

`driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//li[@ng-repeat="viewt in viewst track by viewt._id"]')`[here_is_index(even 0 idk)]

and choose needed by indexing. *It's really hard to help you without html code...*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That still gives me "Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".dropdown-menu"}

Code line is: 

dropdown = Select(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.dropdown-menu'))

I am really trying to select the submenu line which is "All Tasks For Reports"

Comment: @rlpmeredith try update

Comment: Hmmmm. I really can't work out how to post the html! Obviously I would if I could. The page html is short.

Comment: The update gives me list index out of range even with 0! I dont get it. It wont find anything!

Comment: @rlpmeredith so post html